# onClick in one fragment, change textview in another fragment via same host activity

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have two fragment in an activity. Based on category selected in a categoryFragment.java sub category will be displayed in another fragment (SubcategoryFragment.java)

As of now when a textview is clicked in categoryfragment, I am displaying the subcategory. Rather being replaced the textview is appended on click.

I even tried replcae the fragment. But cannot able to commit fragment transaction twice. Please let me know where I go wrong.

**MainActivity**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

        itemsList.add(new Items(1,"Drinks","Coca Cola",10,1,"image.jpg"));
        itemsList.add(new Items(2,"Drinks","Pepsi",30,1,"image.jpg"));
        itemsList.add(new Items(3,"Food","Briyani",30,1,"image.jpg"));
        itemsList.add(new Items(4,"Food","meals",30,1,"image.jpg"));

        bundle.putParcelableArrayList("itemsList",  itemsList);
        bundle.putString("category","none");
        frg.setArguments(bundle);
       frg1.setArguments(bundle);
        transaction.add(R.id.My_Container_1_ID, frg, "Frag_Top_tag");
       transaction.add(R.id.My_Container_2_ID, frg1, "Frag_Middle_tag");
        transaction.commit();
    }

    @Override
    public void onFragmentInteraction(Integer id) {
        String category = "";
        itemsList.add(new Items(1,"Drinks","Coca Cola",10,1,"image.jpg"));
        itemsList.add(new Items(2,"Drinks","Pepsi",30,1,"image.jpg"));
        itemsList.add(new Items(3,"Food","Briyani",30,1,"image.jpg"));
        itemsList.add(new Items(4,"Food","meals",30,1,"image.jpg"));
        for(int i=0; i<itemsList.size();i++)
        {
            if( i == itemsList.get(id).getItemId() - 1)
               category = itemsList.get(i).getCategory();
        }

        ((SubCategoryFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.My_Container_2_ID)).getSelectedCategory(category);

    }
```

**CategoryFragmnet.java**

```
@Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view;
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_category, container, false);

        Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();
        ArrayList<Items> myValue;
        myValue = bundle.getParcelableArrayList("itemsList");

        TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(hello);
        textView.setOnClickListener(this);

        String cat="";
        for(int i=0; i<myValue.size();i++)
        {
            cat = cat + myValue.get(i).getCategory() +" ";
        }
        textView.setText(cat);
        return view;
    }
    OnFragmentInteractionListener dataPasser;
    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        if (context instanceof OnFragmentInteractionListener) {
            mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) context;
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                    + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
        }

        dataPasser = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) context;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId())
        {
            case R.id.hello:
                mListener.onFragmentInteraction(1);
                break;
        }
    }

      public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
        // TODO: Update argument type and name
        void onFragmentInteraction(Integer id);
    }
```

**SubCategoryFragment.java**

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view;
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_sub_category, container, false);
        return view;
    }

    public void onViewCreated(View v, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(v, savedInstanceState);
        Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();
        myValue = bundle.getParcelableArrayList("itemsList");
        String category = bundle.getString("category");
        textView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.subh);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume(){
        super.onResume();
    }
    public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
        if (mListener != null) {
            mListener.OnSubFragmentInteractionListener(uri);
        }
    }

    OnSubFragmentInteractionListener dataPasser;
    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        if (context instanceof OnSubFragmentInteractionListener) {
            mListener = (OnSubFragmentInteractionListener) context;
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                    + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
        }

        dataPasser = (OnSubFragmentInteractionListener) context;
    }

    public interface OnSubFragmentInteractionListener {
        void OnSubFragmentInteractionListener(Uri uri);
    }

    public void getSelectedCategory(String str)
    {
        textView = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.subh);
        textView.setText(" ");
       String cat="";
        for(int i=0; i<myValue.size();i++)
        {
            if(str.equals(myValue.get(i).getCategory()))
                cat = cat + myValue.get(i).getSubCategory() +" ";
        }
        textView.setText(cat);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Mayb you can try to pass data between fragments using an interface
Create an interface in first fragment MainActivity implement that interface and the respective method, then call a method that defined in second fragent
Second fragment receive the data through that method. 
Since 2 fragments cannot comminicate directly, so have to use this simple way
hope this helps.

Comment: I can able to pass data from one fragment to another. But my text view in fragment 2 is not getting replaced, Its getting appended.

Comment: try this as reference?(https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html)